# ECDSA for Android using SpongyCastle

Tags: android, encryption-asymmetric, elliptic-curve, ecdsa, spongycastle

I've just added SpongyCastle to Eclipse for my Android Project, however I don't seem to be able to find a single good/complete example of how to use ECDSA for **encryption** & **decryption** of plain texts. I would imagine this should be a 'hello world' for ecnryption libraries.

Can anyone help me with this? or direct me towards some other resource that can help me achieve the same goals?

Thanks.

Comment: I take it that no one's really tried using this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [example](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Elliptic+Curve+Key+Pair+Generation+and+Key+Factories) from bouncycastle.org for generating a key, from there it's just standard use of the KeyPair.  Also @nelenkov wrote a [great article](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/using-ecdh-on-android.html) (as usual) on Elliptic curve on Android

```
ECGenParameterSpec ecGenSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("prime192v1");
//using spongycastle provider
KeyPairGenerator  g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "SC");

g.initialize(ecGenSpec, new SecureRandom());

KeyPair pair = g.generateKeyPair();
```